recordbatchreader failed when reading parquet file
I tried to use arrow::recoredbatchreader to read multiple rowgroups from a parquet file in parallelism. I use GetRecordBatchReader to acquire recordbatchreader. However, I noticed that when the number of task exceeded the number of cores, the reading would stop at RETURN_NOT_OK(ReadNext(&batch));. The recordbatchreader only works when the number of tasks is less than the number of cores.
The arrow version that I use is 14.0.0.
And here is my codes:
#include <arrow/api.h>
#include <arrow/io/api.h>
#include <arrow/result.h>
#include <arrow/status.h>
#include <arrow/util/thread_pool.h>
#include <arrow/util/parallel.h>
#include <arrow/util/range.h>
#include <parquet/arrow/reader.h>
#include <parquet/arrow/writer.h>
#include <parquet/column_reader.h>
#include <parquet/column_scanner.h>
#include <parquet/exception.h>
#include <parquet/types.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

template <class FUNCTION, typename T,
          typename R = typename arrow::internal::call_traits::return_type<FUNCTION>::ValueType>
arrow::Future<std::vector<R>> ParallelForAsync_test(
    std::vector<T> inputs, FUNCTION&& func, 
    arrow::internal::Executor* executor = arrow::internal::GetCpuThreadPool()) {
  std::vector<arrow::Future<R>> futures(inputs.size());
  for (size_t i = 0; i < inputs.size(); ++i) {
    ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(futures[i], executor->Submit(func, i, std::move(inputs[i])));
  }
  return All(std::move(futures))
      .Then([](const std::vector<arrow::Result<R>>& results) -> arrow::Result<std::vector<R>> {
        return  arrow::internal::UnwrapOrRaise(results);
      });
}

arrow::Result<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array>> ChunkedArrayToArray(std::shared_ptr<arrow::ChunkedArray> chunked_array) {
        auto arrays = chunked_array->chunks();
        std::shared_ptr<arrow::Array> result;
        ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(result, arrow::Concatenate(arrays));

        return result;
    }

arrow::Status read_whole_file(std::string file, int batch_size, int &size) {

  ::arrow::MemoryPool* pool = ::arrow::default_memory_pool();

  auto reader_properties = parquet::ReaderProperties(pool);
  reader_properties.set_buffer_size(4096 * 4);
  reader_properties.enable_buffered_stream();
  
  auto arrow_reader_props = parquet::ArrowReaderProperties();
  arrow_reader_props.set_batch_size(4 * 1024);
  arrow_reader_props.set_use_threads(true);

  parquet::arrow::FileReaderBuilder reader_builder;
  ARROW_RETURN_NOT_OK(reader_builder.OpenFile(file, false, reader_properties));
  reader_builder.memory_pool(pool);
  reader_builder.properties(arrow_reader_props);

  std::unique_ptr<parquet::arrow::FileReader> arrow_reader;
  ARROW_ASSIGN_OR_RAISE(arrow_reader, reader_builder.Build());

  auto p_reader = arrow_reader->parquet_reader();
  int nrgs = p_reader->metadata()->num_row_groups();
  int nrows = p_reader->metadata()->num_rows();

  int ncolumns = p_reader->metadata()->num_columns();
  auto cpu_executor = ::arrow::internal::GetCpuThreadPool();

  int rg_batchsize = nrgs / batch_size;

  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatchReader>> vec_reader;
  std::cout << "total has " << nrgs << " rowgroups" << std::endl;
  for (int j = 0; j <= rg_batchsize; j++) {
    std::shared_ptr<arrow::RecordBatchReader> rb_reader;
    arrow_reader->GetRecordBatchReader(
        arrow::internal::Iota(j * batch_size, std::min((j+1) * batch_size, nrgs)), &rb_reader);
        std::cout << "task "<< j << " range [" << j*batch_size << "," << std::min((j+1) * batch_size, nrgs) << "]" << std::endl;
    vec_reader.emplace_back(rb_reader);
  }
  size = vec_reader.size();
  std::cout << size << std::endl;
  auto thread_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto read_recordbatch = [ncolumns, thread_start](size_t i, std::shared_ptr<::arrow::RecordBatchReader> reader)
        -> ::arrow::Result<bool>{
        auto io_start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto result = reader->ToTable();
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<::arrow::Array>> vec_array;
        if (result.ok()) {
          auto table = *result;
          for (int i = 0; i < ncolumns; i++) {
            auto result = ChunkedArrayToArray(table->column(i));
            if (result.ok()) {
              auto array = *result;
              vec_array.emplace_back(array);
            }
          }
        }
        auto io_end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        
        reader->Close();
        std::cout << "thread " << i << " " << vec_array[0]->length() << " rows " 
                    << "start_overhead " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(io_start-thread_start).count() << " ms "
                    << "io_overhead " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(io_end-io_start).count() << " ms" << std::endl;
        return true;

  };

  auto re = ParallelForAsync_test(std::move(vec_reader), read_recordbatch, cpu_executor)
                .MoveResult();
  auto re_chka = re.ValueOrDie();

  return ::arrow::Status::OK();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  std::string file = argv[1];
  int batch_size = atoi(argv[2]);
  int size = 0;
  auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  read_whole_file(file, batch_size, size);
  auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  printf("%d thread(s) %f ms\n", size, std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(end-start).count());

  return 0;
}

